# Easy Digital Downloads - how to get discount amount?

Tags: php, wordpress, easy-digital-downloads

I tried this code to get amount of discount but the problem is what is the first prameter :

```
edd_get_discount_amount('off1');
```

The `off1` is name of discount.

Is above code right according to the usage of `edd_get_discount_amount` function.

Answer (score 0):

edd_get_discount_amount expects an integer as parameter, this integer should be the id of the discount you would like to retrieve

```
edd_get_discount_amount( $discount_id )
```

[easy digital downloads discount-functions.php](https://github.com/easydigitaldownloads/easy-digital-downloads/blob/2e6667f939de55ef2e6f920f4463ee83b27fddd6/includes/discount-functions.php)